# Duplicate Question, versus Updated Answers, regarding Certification

Tags: discussion, duplicates

> This is a discussion post.  Please read on for the specifics.

- Old Question: [Is there such a thing as a Ubuntu Certified Engineer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166692/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-ubuntu-certified-engineer)
- New Question: [Are there any Ubuntu Courses or training programs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648310/are-there-any-ubuntu-online-courses-training-programs?noredirect=1#comment930499_648310)

Currently, the Old Question is old as sin, with all the answers out of date, and no updates for at least a couple years.  The correct answer is "There is no Ubuntu specific certification or training programs" nowadays, given that the Ubuntu technical certifications were discontinued, even as part of Advantage.

Given this, the New Question was asked, and I posted my answer, pointing to other Linux-generic certifications that would work, given there is no Ubuntu certification anymore.  As such, I'm considering the Old Question abandoned.

So, this ultimately spawns this question/discussion: Which question should we consider as valid, AND, at what point can we consider an answer-accepted question outdated, invalid, and abandoned?

Answer (score 1):

Why prefer a new question just because its new?

To my view you are confusing things, there are 2 points there that should not be mixed and considered the same:

- Is there something offered via official channels on the same level as eg: RHCE?
- Is there any course out there that can be applied to general Linux, and hence can be applied to Ubuntu?

The answer for the first is `no`, the answer to the second is `yes`, but since we know the answer to the second one to be common I do not see any value asking it, at all.

I hope that this solves your confusion and explains why I think my question should not be closed in favor for the most recent one.

They are not the same questions and deserve separate answers.